# Redirect to XML file and back to PHP page possible?

Tags: php, xml, redirect

I'm currently coding an ID filter, whenever a user submits an ID it will pick out all the orders and filters out all the ID's you DON'T want to see from the XML file.

a little preview - XML

```
<filter><!-- Copy filter-item and put the order-id in as the value to skip it-->
    <filter_item>1138850639</filter_item><filter_item>1138371172</filter_item><filter_item>1137835945</filter_item></filter>
</root>
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['load'])) 
{
    

    $orderFilter = $_POST['orderItemFilter'];
    
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("Config.xml");
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());
    $itemsNode = $sxe->filter;
    $itemsNode->addChild("filter_item", $orderFilter);
    $sxe->asXML("Config.xml");  
}
```

Now the problem is that the file itself does contain the ID, but the Config.xml HAS TO BE RUNNED to be able to display the final order page. Is there a way to redirect from an XML file to return to the previous page?

Answer (score 0):

There are two mentioned to do this.

First you can do this in Javascript.

```
 javascript:history.go(-1)
```

Second, you can do this in PHP, remember it is not ggood idea to because it will not work on HTTPS and headers can be hijacked and reirect to unwanted pages.

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```